# How to compile apps to Android TV Box?

Tags: android, android-tv

I am quite new to Android TV apps development. So , i search for Android TV Box in the internet , i am quite confuse that where i can connect the usb cable to compile my code , so then i can install a new app to the TV Box.

I am quite clear to the Android TV apis , which i already gone through the brief in Android Studio. So , only i need to know how can i install an app to Android TV box.

[Link](http://www.amazon.in/iRevo-Smart-Android-Box-Mouse/dp/B00U2J3A2Y/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1465233969&sr=8-2&keywords=android%20tv%20box)

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: This ends up being device specific, and many cheap import devices may not offer documentation at all.  Your most practical approach may be web searches on particular models, checking enthusiast sites like xda developers, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I've made in that way (be sure to enable developers mode on tv box first):

- on tv box installed app from google play: [Wifi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en).
- launched it on tv box
- in android studio's terminal typed: adb connect 192.168.1.2:5555 (will be written in wifi adb)
- lauched project directly on tv box from android studio

Comment: I installed the Wifi ADB app, and it works like a charm!

Comment: the app doesn't work on android tv.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal of android studio :

> ```
> adb kill-server
> adb start-server
> adb connect *.*.*.* ==> address of your Android Tv Box
> ```

and run the project .

Comment: I didn't have adb in path, so I had to do: `~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server`. But other than that this answer was perfect for me, even though my ONN Android box is 10 and docs seem to say wifi debugging only works on >=11